# My linux server "Number of processes created" and "Context switches" are growing incredibly fast

Tags: linux, process, threads, stats, context-switch

I have a strange behaviour in my server :-/. Is a OpenVZ VPS (I think is OpenVZ, because `/proc/user_beancounters` exists and `df -h` returns /dev/simfs drive. Also `ifconfig` returns `venet0`). When I do `cat /proc/stat`, I can see how each second about 50-100 processes are created and happens about 800k-1200k context switches! All that info is with the server completely idle, no traffic nor programs running.

Top shows 0 load average and 100% idle CPU.

I've closed all non-needed services (httpd, mysqld, sendmail, nagios, named...) and the problem still happens. I do `ps -ALf` each second too and I don't see any changes, only a new `ps` process is created each time and the PID is just the same as before + 1, so new processes are not created, so I thought that process growing in `cat /proc/stat` must be threads (Yes, seems that `processes` in `/proc/stat` counts threads creation too as this states: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:8NLgzKEzHQQJ:www.linuxhowtos.org/System/procstat.htm&hl=es&tbo=d&gl=es&strip=1).

I've changed to `/proc` dir and done `cat [PID]\status` with all PIDs listed with `ls` (Including kernel ones) and in any process `voluntary_ctxt_switches` nor `nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches` are growing at the same speed as `cat /proc/stat` does (just a few tens/second), `Threads` keeps the same also.

I've done `strace -p PID` to all process too so I can see if any process is crating threads or something but the only process that has a bit of movement is `ssh` and that movement is `read`/`write` operations because of the data is sending to my terminal.

After that, I've done `vmstat -s` and saw that `forks` is growing at the same speed `processes` in `/proc/stat` does. As http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork says, each `fork()` creates a new PID but my server PID is not growing!

The last thing I can think of is that all process data that `proc/stat` and `vmstat -s` show is shared with all the other VPS stored in the same machine, but I don't know if that is correct... If someone can throw some light on this I would be really grateful.

Comment: What kind of VPS? Xen, VMWare etc.

Comment: I think OpenVZ, because `/proc/user_beancounters` exists and `df -h` returns `/dev/simfs` drive. Also `ifconfig` returns `venet0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case I would assume that your kernel is not virtualizing some or all values in /proc/stat, so what you're seeing should be caused by activity in other containers or in the hardware node itself.

You haven't mentioned your specific kernel version so we can't check for sure, but a similar issue was discussed in http://forum.openvz.org/index.php?t=msg&goto=44507& .

PS: check out /proc/vz/vestat instead.

Comment: My kernel is `Linux version 2.6.32-6-pve`. Reading the forum you linked, finally I've reached the same conclusion, OpenVZ is not isolating /proc/stat.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen at least one similar question here about someone with 2 identical ubuntu servers behind a load balancer...and I will tell you what I told him:

syspro ("system profiler")

or try stuffing some limits in /etc/security/limits.conf
Apply the limits to both machines and compare which executables show up.
It will at least flag a process or thread and narrow the list of suspects.

man limits.conf:   hard & soft for file descriptors, mem locked, stack size,cpu time, nice levels, etc

Comment: I don't think you understood the question. I don't want to limit. I want to know why all that happens.

Comment: I added a clarification. Put the same limits for the same programs and see which programs get reported and **HOW MUCH** they are over limits. Some disparity should emerge